# Prevent div click open modal on certain condition

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

There is a way to prevent open modal under certain condition?

I have to use a `div` and click it to open a modal:

```
<div ng-class="{'prevent-modal': condition}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalId">SomeText</div>
```

when `condition` is `true` I want to prevent modal to open

I know that using a `button` I can use `ng-disabled` to avoid click, but it obviously not work on `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/) of yours it is difficult to be sure 100% but try this:

```
<div data-toggle="{{openModal()}}" data-target="#modalId">SomeText</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
//...
function openModal() {
  if(<your_condition>) {
    return "modal";
  }
}
//...
```

Comment: It is exactly what I want and it works, only change `data-toggle="openModal()"` with `data-toggle="{{openModal()}}"`

Comment: Great! I updated the answer with your clarification:)